# Can't click on label to select checkbox with Bootstrap checkbox layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

So I have the following code:

```
// the loop
                $countId = 0;
                $dateOnce = '';
                foreach ($postDates as $post):
                    if (substr($post->post_date, 0, 7) != $dateOnce) {
                        echo'
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label for="filterByPostDate-' . $countId . '">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="filterByPostDate-' . substr($post->post_date, 0, 7) . '" class="postDateFilters postDateFilterCb-' . $countId . '" name="filterByPostDate-' . $countId . '" value="' . substr($post->post_date, 0, 7) . '" '; if (isset($_SESSION["filterByPostDate"])) { $key = array_search(substr($post->post_date, 0, 7), $_SESSION["filterByPostDate"]); } else { $key = false; } if($key !== false) { echo 'checked'; } echo ' />
                                    ' . date('M, Y', strtotime($post->date_part)) . '
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        ';
                    }
                    $dateOnce = substr($post->post_date, 0, 7);
                $countId++;
                endforeach;
                // END the loop
```

Which outputs checkboxes and labels for the wordpress frontend.
But when I click on the label for each checkbox the checkbox doesn't get selected.

Here is a [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/02bts6oq/) which shows the problem.

Cheers for the help.

Comment: Label "for" and checkbox "id" must be same. 
[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/02bts6oq/2/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you must include the `id` of your element in 
`<label for="">`

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <label for="filterByPostDate-2011-12">
    <input type="checkbox" id="filterByPostDate-2011-12" class="postDateFilters postDateFilterCb-0" name="filterByPostDate-0" value="2011-12"  />
    Dec, 2011
  </label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox">
  <label for="filterByPostDate-2012-01">
    <input type="checkbox" id="filterByPostDate-2012-01" class="postDateFilters postDateFilterCb-6" name="filterByPostDate-6" value="2012-01"  />
    Jan, 2012
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Haha can't believe I missed that. Thanks for the help ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Label attribute `for` and checkbox `id` must be same.

```html
<label for="checkbox1">I have a bike</label>
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">


<label for="checkbox2">I have a car</label>
<input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Car">
```

Answer (score 3):

You actually don't need the `for` attribute on your label at all, for the browser to let you click and select the checkbox . If you wrap your `<label>` tag around the input, then the browser knows that it is 'for' that field.

*However*, you should also include the `for` attribute, as not all assistive technologies recognise the relationship between label and input. As mentioned, the biggest issue with your code is that you are saying the label is 'for' something other than the input that it is wrapped around.

Here is an updated working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/BrettEast/ffgL77qo/, using the correct for attribute.

Comment: Should use  it if you are wanting to be accessibility compliant though

Comment: @charlietfl very true! Both, should be done, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The attribute `for` in `label` tag should be the same value of the `id` attribute of the field. Checkout [this reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp). In your code sample it is obviously two diffirent values.

Otherwise, you may omit the `for` attribute and keeping the input field inside it:

```
<label>Check this
  <input type="checkbox" name="any" value="1">
</label>
```

[**jsbin**](http://output.jsbin.com/gonuqusewu) demo.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code. You should you `for` in the label and `id` for checkbox. I wish you already got the answer.

```html
<div class="checkbox">
   <label for="filterByPostDate-2017-05">
   <input type="checkbox" id="filterByPostDate-2017-05" class="postDateFilters postDateFilterCb-01" name="filterByPostDate-01" value="2017-05"/>May, 2017
  </label>
</div>
       
<div class="checkbox">
  <label for="filterByPostDate-2017-06">
   <input type="checkbox" id="filterByPostDate-2017-06" class="postDateFilters postDateFilterCb-02" name="filterByPostDate-2" value="2017-06" />June, 2017
  </label>
</div>
```